# Is the norm $||\tilde{f}||=||f||$ if $f=\pi\circ\tilde{f}$ where $\pi$ is the quotient map

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces, $f\in B(X,Y)$. Let $\pi$ be the quotient map: $X\rightarrow X/\mbox{Ker}(f)$. Then we can define $\tilde{f}$ s.t. $f=\tilde{f}\circ\pi$. I want to know if $||\tilde{f}||=||f||$.

---

It is easy to show that $||f||\leq ||\tilde{f}||$, but I don't know how to show the reverse one.

Comment: $\pi$ maps the open unit ball of $X$ to the open unit ball of $X/\ker f$.

Comment: Do you mean $f=\tilde{f}\circ\pi$? The range of $\pi\circ\tilde{f}$ is $X/\ker f$, not $Y$

Comment: @Aweygan sorry i will fix it